# Match data set against the predefined data-set and store it in a hash format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash

I need to be able to match the data from an array of random ints and pass them to a hash in a specific outline while matching the random data against a defined set of data.

```
empty = {}
defined = [1,2,17,34,3,18,17]
dataset_one = [1,0,17]
dataset_two = [3,18,2,4]


desired = { 1 => 3, 17 => 2}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
defined.each{ |item| 
  dataset_one.each{ |key|
   if item == key
    empty[key] = nil
   end
  dataset_two.each{ |value|
   if item = value 
   empty[key] = value
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: You rarely can ask a question unambiguously when you frame it in terms of a single example. This is no exception. State your question in words, at the beginning, and then use the example for illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pair up the keys and the values, eliminate those where the key is not in the predetermined set of data, then turn the list of key-value pairs into a hash.

```
dataset_one.zip(dataset_two).select { |k, v| defined.include?(k) }.to_h
# => {1=>3, 17=>2}
```

It is not clear from the question if you need to check both keys and values against `defined`; if so, the modification is trivial:

```
dataset_one.zip(dataset_two).select { |k, v|
  defined.include?(k) && defined.include?(v)
}.to_h
```

If speed is important, you might want to turn some of your stuff into sets (`defined` in particular).

Comment: something like this i feel like this statement would explain it better, if dataset_one contains a value from defined and dataset_two contains a value from defined pass those values into a hash formatted in hash = {dataset_one: => dataset_two}